# What's the difference between button.click event and button.command event?

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

Whats the difference between [Button.Click Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.click.aspx) and [Button.Command Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command.aspx) in asp.net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the documentation implies,the Button.Command event allows you to specify a "command" so that you can differentiate between which button was clicked,etc.

Comment: Can you provide a real world example, please?

Comment: Well, one common example that has been useful to me is a grid where each row has a button (or link) for "Edit" or "Delete". Specify those values for the "Command" and then you know which button was clicked

Comment: Adding to Bryce's comment, you would use the command so you can have one method (Some generic event handler) that handles all buttons. (at least this is how i use it) You just use a switch: case; to determine what type of button was clicked and determine what to do from there. You could call another method or just do the work, whatever..

Answer (score 0):

**Button Click and Command behaves with the same way. Both will perform PostBack operation and has small difference.**

1. If a button has both Click and Command events associated with it, then Click eventHandler is performed first, then commandHandler is performed.
2. **Click event does not send any parameters whereas Command will send parameters like CommandName and CommandAgrument to codeBehind code.** So, this helps developers to find which button is triggered when they have multiple buttons.